# How to show a tutorial for vscode extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am building an extension for VsCode and wanted to show a small tutorial on how to use it, but I can't find an appropriate API for that. Obviously, I can save some variables in the global state to follow user progress and use some FE framework to do some drawing in a webview, but it feels very custom. I saw that VSCode shows a tutorial on initial installation and hoped I can do the same.

Answer (score 1):

In VSCode it is called a walkthrough and is defined simply in package.json. Here is a link to this API: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.walkthroughs

and this an example project https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/main/getting-started-sample/package.json#L39

It is pretty easy to define and use. It accepts text, media files, and markdown files.